# Publish often fails if OAuth is enabled on Deployer

Tags: web8.5, deployer

On SDL Web 8.5, publish often fails and following error log is output to Content Deployer's log.

> ERROR DefaultOAuthToken - Token expired

So I disabled OAuth in Content Deployer, then this error disappeared.
I modifid following values to 'false' in `cd_ambient_conf.xml`.

```
<Security OAuthEnabled="false">
    <Rules Enabled="false"/>
</Security>
```

How does this error occur?

Is it possible to make publish succeed stalby while OAuth is enabled?

Comment: Are you sure it’s related? We use OAUTH always in cloud, don’t have this issue. The “token expired” error is expected, as they need to be renewed regularly and the software deals with it transparently.

Comment: I'm not sure, Maybe your system times on machines may be out of sync. Check system time and time zones?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am getting Token expired  during publishing  in web 8.5 now as well , the Token seem to  remain  expired the even when the time stamp has changed  and i get a transport service failure.

Answer (score 1):

As Nuno mentioned, We used OAuth always in the cloud and on-premise customers environment, don’t have this issue. The “**Token expired**” error is expected, as they need to be renewed regularly and the software deals with it transparently.

Make sure your system times on machines may be out of sync and check system date and time zones of all the scale out the environment of CM and CD, and WebApp servers to be same.

Just to note, OOTB bearer token expires in every 5 min and that can be configured in **cd_ambient_confi.xml tag** `<TokenExpireTime TimeInSeconds="300"/>`

I hope it helps to understand.